# Optimize WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, optimization

For the homepage WP_Query loop, I need to get the most recent 20 articles, specifically to display the page title, excerpt, category, and date. I am doing the following:

```
 $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 20,
    'update_post_term_cache' => false, // don't retrieve post terms
    'update_post_meta_cache' => false, // don't retrieve post meta
    'cat' => -2301, //exclude this category
    'orderby'       => 'post_date',
    'no_found_rows' => true, // counts posts, remove if pagination required           
 );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

However, I am seeing a lot of DB queries like:

```
SELECT tr.object_id
FROM wp_term_relationships AS tr
INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy AS tt...
```

As well as

```
SELECT post_id, meta_key, meta_value
FROM wp_postmeta
WHERE post_id IN ....
```

Which uses up server resources, particular as there are 25'000 posts and 50'000 tags. Is there a more efficient method to run this query, given that I only need the fields as per above?

Comment: Why are you running a custom query on your homepage?

Comment: You're doing expensive things, stuff like filtering out a category isn't super fast and requires a JOIN to check the taxonomy. You've even added pagination, followed by a parameter that has a comment saying remove if you need pagination. Are you sure you wouldn't be better off using the `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the existing query or caching the output?

Comment: @TomJNowell I totally understand your point but I don't agree with you about the critic about the added pagination and added a parameter to avoid pagination; as far I know `post_per_page` is the only way to set the amount of posts you want to get, even if you don't want pagination like this case. Combining `post_per_page` and `no_found_rows` is the only way to set the limit amount of posts to get and avoid the counting of total rows for pagination; so combining both is good if you don't want pagination. (`nopaging` parameter set to true shows all posts ignoring `post_per_page` parameter).

Comment: you should look into *persistent object caching* solutions @josh